# Помогите со склонением

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать:
*Я узнала, что **орнамента** не может быть без симметрии.*
Или:
*Я узнала, что **орнамент** не может быть без симметрии.*

И, если не затруднит, ткните носом в правило. Спасибо.

Comment: Да нету тут правила. Вернее есть, но гласит, что оба варианта возможны, Посмотрите, миллион вопросов подобных - и все хотят "правила". http://rus.stackexchange.com/search?q=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8+%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9 Мне в разговорной речи больше нравится родительный падеж.

Comment: Спасибо, сто лет живи, сто лет учись.

Comment: В качестве справки — ленточный орнамент симметрии не требует, а также сетчатый, шрифтовой, арабеска... Хорошо бы не распространять непроверенные данные.

Comment: Комментарий от @behemothus выше был бы уместен, если бы речь в вопросе шла о конкуренции родительного падежа с винительным, а не с именительным.

Answer (score 1):

Тут всё зависит от того, что именно вы хотите сказать. Понятно, что здесь смущает слово "быть". Давайте вместе разберемся, что же Вы хотели сказать. 1. Я узнала, что без СИММЕТРИИ (логическое ударение) не может быть никакого орнамента. 2. Я узнала, что ни один ОРНАМЕНТ (логическое ударение) не может существовать без симметрии". Как видите, эти предложения неоднозначны. Выбирайте любой из Ваших вариантов, в зависимости от того, какой смысл Вы хотели донести этой фразой.